# What is this plastic basin on the back of my fridge, and does it require any special care?

Tags: refrigerator

While cleaning my kitchen and behind my fridge, I found this part on its back. It was filled with a moldy liquid that looked like water. I threw the liquid away and cleaned the part. I’ve added a bit of water back (not as much as it had) and put the part back in its place.

[image]
[image]

I found the manual for [a similar fridge model](https://www.indesitservice.co.uk/lib/manuals/BAN134_144_12NF_NFS_NFG_19505276500.pdf) but I see no reference to the part.

My question is **what is this part for, and how should I take care of it?**

Comment: Looks like a condensation or frost-melt catch basin. It's probably expected that it'll only get occasional use, such as during the defrost cycle, and that any water collected will evaporate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is almost certainly the drip pan, and it is intended to catch condensation flowing from the condensation/defrost drains in the fridge/freezer.
This water should just evaporate into the surrounding air over time.
Cleaning it occasionally is not a bad idea, but it is not necessary to 'replace' any of the water you may find in it.